# Load array field in csv data file into Athena table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

This is a sample row in input data file with two fields - dept and names

```
dept,names
Mathematics,[foo,bar,alice,bob]
```

Here, 'name' is an array of String and I want to load it as array of String Athena.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

To have a valid CSV file, make sure you put quotes around your array:

```
Mathematics,"[foo,bar,alice,bob]"
```

If you can remove the "[" and "]" the solution below becomes even easier and you can just split without the regex.

```
Better: Mathematics,"foo,bar,alice,bob"
```

First create a simple table from CSV with just strings:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.mydataset (
  `dept` string,
  `names` string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = ',',
  'field.delim' = ',',
  'quoteChar' = '"',
  "separatorChar" = ',',
  'collection.delim' = ',',
  'mapkey.delim' = ':'
) LOCATION 's3://<your location>'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false')
```

Then create a view which uses a regex to remove your '[' and ']' characters, then splits the rest by ',' into an array.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW mydataview AS
SELECT  dept, 
        split(regexp_extract(names, '^\[(.*)\]$', 1), ',') as names
FROM mydataset
```

Then use the view for your queries. I am not 100% sure as I've only spent like 12 hours using Athena.

--

Note that in order to use the quotes, you need to use OpenCSVSerde, the 'lazyserde' won't work as it does support quotes. lazyserde DOES support internal arrays, but you can't use the ',' as a separator in that case. If you want to try that, your data would look like:

```
Better: Mathematics,foo|bar|alice|bob
```

In that case this MIGHT work directly:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.mydataset (
      `dept` string,
      `names` array<string>
    )
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
    WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
      'serialization.format' = ',',
      'field.delim' = ',',
      'quoteChar' = '"',
      "separatorChar" = ',',
      'collection.delim' = '|',
      'mapkey.delim' = ':'
    ) LOCATION 's3://<your location>'
    TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false')
```

Note how collection.delim = '|', which should translate your field directly to an array.

Sorry I don't have time to test this, I'll be happy to update my answer if you can confirm what works. Hopefully this get's you started.

Answer (score 0):

Andy's answer is one of the approach you can take. I think you don't need the additional regex even. Just by using `org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde`, you can get the whole array as a string. Only thing is if you need to wrap the array within the double quote like "[foo,bar,alice,bob]". It will be treated as a whole string